# Null pointer, Context in activity intent for bottom navigation

Tags: java, android

This app has two activities and I want to switch between them with the BottomNavigationView. Declaring an intent inside the switch statement throws a null pointer exception. MainActivity.java was changed to SpecialsActivity.java. The second activity is PizzaActivity.  The bottom navigation is controlled with BottomNavigationBuilder.java.

example stack trace:

```
W/System.err: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.Context android.content.Context.getApplicationContext()' on a null object reference
```

what I've tried:

```
Intent PizzaIntent = new Intent(this, PizzaActivity.class);
                                    //Intent PizzaIntent = new Intent(getCallingActivity(), PizzaActivity.class);
                                    //Intent PizzaIntent = new Intent( getBaseContext(),PizzaActivity.class);
                                    //Intent PizzaIntent = new Intent(BottomNavigationBuilder.this, PizzaActivity.class);
                                    //Intent PizzaIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), PizzaActivity.class);
                                    startActivity(PizzaIntent);
```

BottomNavigationBuilder.java

```
public class BottomNavigationBuilder extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Context context;
    private BottomNavigationView bottomNavigation;

    public BottomNavigationBuilder(Context context, BottomNavigationView findViewById) {
        this.context = context;
        this.bottomNavigation = findViewById;
    }

    public BottomNavigationBuilder setBaseConfig() {
        setTextVisible();
        setSelectedListener();
        return this;
    }

    private void setTextVisible() {
        bottomNavigation.setLabelVisibilityMode(LabelVisibilityMode.LABEL_VISIBILITY_LABELED);
    }

    public void displayToast(String message) {
        Toast.makeText(this.context, message,
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    private void setSelectedListener() {
        BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener navigationItemSelectedListener =
                new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {

                    String url;

                    @Override
                    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {

                        switch (item.getItemId()) {

                            case R.id.action_specials:
                                displayToast("Specials clicked");
                                break;

                            case R.id.action_pizza:
                                displayToast("Pizza clicked");

                                try {
                                    Intent PizzaIntent = new Intent(this, PizzaActivity.class);
                                    //Intent PizzaIntent = new Intent(getCallingActivity(), PizzaActivity.class);
                                    //Intent PizzaIntent = new Intent( getBaseContext(),PizzaActivity.class);
                                    //Intent PizzaIntent = new Intent(BottomNavigationBuilder.this, PizzaActivity.class);
                                    //Intent PizzaIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), PizzaActivity.class);
                                    startActivity(PizzaIntent);
                                } catch (Exception e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }


                                break;

                            case R.id.action_stromboli:
                                displayToast("Stromboli clicked");
                                break;

                            case R.id.action_salad:
                                displayToast("Salad clicked");
                                break;

                            case R.id.action_drinks:
                                displayToast("Drinks clicked");
                                break;

                            default:
                                // none
                        }
                        return true;
                    }
                };
        bottomNavigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(navigationItemSelectedListener);
    }

    public BottomNavigationView getBottomNavigation() {
        return bottomNavigation;
    }
}
```

SpecialsActivity.java

```
public class SpecialsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private BottomNavigationView bottomNavigation;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_specials);
        setItemId();
        setView();
    }

    private void setItemId() {
        bottomNavigation = findViewById(R.id.bottom_nav);
    }

    private void setView() {
        initNavigationView();
    }

    private void initNavigationView() {
        bottomNavigation = new BottomNavigationBuilder(this, bottomNavigation)
                .setBaseConfig()
                .getBottomNavigation();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't instantiate Activities directly. You can't directly pass components between them. You don't even need an Activity for this.

Remove the Activity extension:

```
public class BottomNavigationBuilder {
    //...
}
```

Then just use your `context` reference for anything that needs a Context (`new Intent(context, PizzaActivity.class)`, `context.startActivity()`, etc).

You also don't need to reassign `bottomNavigation` after passing it to the builder. It's the same instance, so any changes made to `bottomNavigation` inside the Builder are also made to `bottomNavigation` outside.

Comment: Thank you for helping with this problem. This fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that the reason that you are getting this error is because of where you are placing this statement. Currently, it is like:

```
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
    //.....
    Intent PizzaIntent = new Intent(this, PizzaActivity.class);
```

Try changing the `this` keyword in the `Intent` constructor to the `ApplicationContext` by doing:

```
//Enter your Application's context below.
Intent PizzaIntent = new Intent(context, PizzaActivity.class);
```

Now, the `Intent` should work fine inside `onNavigationItemSelected`. `context` is from your class's constructor. However, since your class extends `AppCompatActivity`, you can also do `getApplicationContext()`. If you have any questions or issues, you can just post it below.

Comment: No, it's not that. The OP is manually constructing an Activity and then trying to use its methods.